# iTunes Com Interface The track is not modifiable

Tags: python, com, itunes, itunes-sdk

I add a file to iTunes through com interface and write in it a comment, but sometimes when writing comments occurs error -

```
com_error: (-2147352567, '\xce\xf8\xe8\xe1\xea\xe0.', (0, None, u'The track is not modifiable.', None, 0, -1610350077), None)
```

Code:

```
def addFile(playlist, filePath, comment):

        IITUserPlaylist = win32com.client.CastTo(playlist, 'IITUserPlaylist')
        resultAdd = IITUserPlaylist.AddFile(filePath)

        if resultAdd == None: return False      #Bad filePath

        while resultAdd.InProgress == True:     #Wait adding files
            print("adding file")

        for number in range(1, resultAdd.Tracks.Count + 1):
            currentTrack = resultAdd.Tracks.Item(number)
            if currentTrack.Kind == 1:
                currentTrack = comment          #Add comment to track 

        return True
```

I think the problem is that at this time iTunes handles the track, because when restart the script error may not occur. Most of all, I'm doing the wrong test on it:

```
    while resultAdd.InProgress == True:     #Wait adding files
        print("adding file")
```

But I did not find in the documentation of other ways.

Sorry, I bad speak at english.

Comment: *"itunce"* - iTunes?! I mean, it's **right there** in the tag you've used!

Comment: Yes, sorry, i made a typo

Comment: empirically it found that the error appears only when you add tracks without id3 tags

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your file is read-only.

Source : got the same problem